# Can I change uuid for network interface in ifcfg-eth* using uuidgen?

Tags: bash, networking, centos, uuid

I'm creating a script which configuration the network interfaces.

The script which generates `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and names  interfaces to my preference.

In `CentOS 6.5`, my understanding is that I also need to update files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth#`.

My question is about the UUID listed in `ifcfg-eth#`.  Can I change this value to any random number using `uuidgen`?  For a network device is it important to do it based on the MAC address or does it not matter?

In other words, could i use the the function below, or will modifying the UUID in this manner cause problems?

```
function make_ifcfg() {
    cat > ifcfg-eth0 <<EOF                                                                 
DEVICE=eth0                                                                                
HWADDR=${intel_MAC_addresses[0]}                                                           
TYPE=Ethernet                                                                              
UUID=$(uuidgen)                                                                          
ONBOOT=yes                                                                                 
NM_CONTROLLED=yes                                                                          
BOOTPROTO=dhcp                                                                             
EOF                                                                                        
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: personally i don't see why not, i usually clone the `ifcfg-*` file and do the same.

Comment: Thanks @Rabin.  Is it necessary to generate the UUID based on the mac address or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I usually just change one number in the string, using the mac address is a nice way to make sure your uuid is unique

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [this article shows how](http://www.itechlounge.net/2014/03/linux-how-to-generate-uuid-for-network-interface-on-rhelcentos/). Keep NetworkManager in line, in case you use it.

Comment: The article is correct that `uuidgen` will generate a new UUID that can be included in the `ifcfg-x` file. However, including the device name with `uuidgen` doesn't do anything at all. To answer the OP's question, yes, you can use any UUID value (generated by `uuidgen` or otherwise).